# Why does my function call another page of my website instead of my modal?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to launch a modal login window from a button. I've done some troubleshooting and the modal works until I place an unordered list with links to another page on my site.

When on index.html, the modal button takes me to the about.html page. When on that page and clicking the modal button again, the modal merely flashes, but does not stay visible.

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navMenu">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="userAccount">
      <button id="myBtn"><i class="material-icons md-48 md-light">account_circle</i></button>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <p>
            Some text in the modal...
          </p>
          <script src="js/userLoginModal.js"></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's my JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the `a` tags, so everything from `<a href="index.html">` to the next `</a>` or the end of the document is all placed inside the link.

Close the `a` tags:

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<!--                         ^^^^  -->
```

same goes for other `a` tags in your document.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to that, Ibrahim. I closed all necessary a tags, but unfortunately, it did not fix the issue.

Comment: @NateTheGreat Instead of clicking, right-click then choose [**Inspect element**](http://www.fluxbytes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/google-chrome-settings-inspect-element.jpg) and see which element you're clicking on.

Comment: Must not have done something right. Went through and re-applied changes and your resolution works. Simple oversight, but I appreciate the second set of eyes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to accomplish your task. Hope it helps!

```js
function toggleOverlay(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        overlay.style.opacity = .6;
        if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            modal.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

```css
div#overlay {
            display: none;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #000;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div#myModal {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 3;
            margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #FFF;
            color: #000;
        }
        div#wrapper {
            position:absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            padding-left:24px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div id="myModal">
    <p>Some text in the modal... ...</p>
    <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">Close</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="navMenu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
        </ul>
    <button onmousedown="toggleOverlay()">account_circle</button>
</div>
```